# Expected Value of Students on a Bus

Tags: probability, soft-question, intuition

There's a question in my probability book that says there are $148$ students on $4$ buses containing $40, 33, 25, 50$ students, respectively. If we let $X$ denote the number of students that were on the bus that a randomly selected student was on. And we let $Y$ be the number of students on the bus of a randomly selected bus driver.

What is $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$?

This is an easy question to answer:

$E[X]=(40^2+33^2+25^2+50^2)(1/148)=39.28$ and $E[Y]=40(1/4)+33(1/4)+25(1/4)+50(1/4) =37$

So $E[X]>E[Y]$ which I wouldn't have guessed.

> What's the intuition behind why these are different?

To me it seemed like these answers would be the same.

Comment: Try 147 student in one bus , 1 student another ; wouldn't you expect close to 147?

Comment: Is there a typo in the formula for $E[Y]$?

Comment: @SammyBlack: Yes there was, fixed now, thanks

Comment: No problem, @MITjanitor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A randomly selected student is more likely to come from a bus with an above-average number of students than from a bus with a below-average number. A randomly selected driver, on the other hand, is equally likely to come from any bus. Thus, the distribution of $X$ is skewed upward from the mean number of students per bus.